# Resizing a partition to increase into space before itself

Tags: high-sierra, disk-utility, partition, apfs, hfs+

**Simple Explanation:**

[image]

**Expanded Explanation:** 
All I want to do is delete `disk0s9` and have `disk0s4` resize and take up the empty space.

**I want to**

1. Delete container `disk4` (`disk0s9`).
2. I don't want the either volume in partitions `disk0s2` or `disk0s8` to absorb the space.
3. I want the volume (`disk0s4`) after it to increase in size, appropriately.

**ISSUE:** 
Every time I attempt to delete / resize using the Diskutil in High Sierra (I miss Yosemite's), the internal disk preceding the disk gets the space :(

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS High Sierra             70.0 GB    disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s8
   4:                 Apple_APFS Container disk4         19.9 GB    disk0s9
   5:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         159.5 GB   disk0s4
   6:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               650.0 MB   disk0s7
```

**ACTIONS ATTEMPTED:** 
Every time I try and resize the partition / remove it, `disk0s2` gets the additional space.

**ASK:**
How do I resize the last portion, while maintain data and not doing a backup / recreate mess?

I know there has gotta be a good way to resize the partitions without having to back everything up and remake from scratch.  I just can't seem to master the new Diskutil when it comes to resizing partitions non-standard ways.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you plan on **any** work on partitions, then the first step is always a **full** backup... But that is your choice, you only have to see the questions on here "how can I get my data, I did not do a backup..."

Answer (score 3):

You can not do what you have proposed by using the tools provided by macOS. Partitions can grow and shrink, but the start of the partition must remain fixed. There are exceptions to this, but none apply in this case. There are third party tools that can move a partition. For example, Paragon offers a [Hard Disk Manager for Mac](https://www.paragon-software.com/hdm-mac/) application which makes the following claim.

> Enables to move the left or right border of the selected partition, thus not only resizing but moving it on the disk

The time required to move all but the smallest partitions is usually quite lengthly. I suppose this might be one reason Apple does not provide this type of tool. An exception would be when resizing a `Apple HFS` partition. The Disk Utility application and the `diskutil` command will move any `Apple_Boot` partition that is the next partition stored on the drive. Usually, this partition and is small in size (under 1 GB) and therefore can be moved fairly quickly. With the introduction of APFS, Apple eliminated the need for partitions of this type.

Comment: I don't have any reason to distrust Hard Disk Manager, but I'd consider any sort of repartitioning operation inherently dangerous. Therefore, I recommend making sure you have at least one good backup of any data you don't want to lose. (And more backups are better!)

Comment: @Gordon Davission: I think the OP already knew a solution to the problem was to make a backup. Simple. Make a backup. Delete the partitions. Create a new partition. Restore from backup. This is why the OP stated the following: **ASK: How do I resize the last portion, while maintain data and not doing a backup / recreate mess?** Personally, instead of spending 40 USD for the Paragon Hard Disk Manager, I would spend 45 USD for a [Toshiba 1TB USB 3.0 2.5" External Hard Drive](https://www.microcenter.com/product/513940/canvio-ready-1tb-usb-30-25-portable-external-hard-drive---black).

Comment: Actually, I was talking about doing the in-place expansion -- that might go sideways, so you should have a backup just in case. If we were talking about the backup/recreate path, I'd recommend at least *two* verified backups. When you delete the original and plan to restore from "backup", that "backup" is not really a backup at all -- it's your primary copy, and you'd better have a real backup as well.

Comment: @Gordon Davission: I alway preferred to have the date transfered to punch cards. I just felt secure when I could see the holes that represented the "ones" in the Hollerith format. I was a 029 man. I left the 026ers to the business programmers. For real security, I would have a sequential index number punched at the end of each card. You know, just in case I dropped the deck. I could recover by running the cards though the sorting machine. By the way, it's cold here in Minnesota.

Comment: @DavidAnderson thanks for confirming the conclusion I didn't wan't to accept (moving files around to make space only to move them back later). I caved and took the long route to my solution... no shortcuts this time :(. The upside was that I'm slowly warming up to APFS and its dynamic abilities. Now if only Apple would let developers play outside the sandbox a bit more in Mojave! Thanks again!